# Memory leak, Node list C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

I have this code from an old exam, which I want fix from its faults. Everytime I call insertlast/insertfirst I allocate new memory for my list which I can't seem to free. I have run it with valgrind and gets a new leak everytime i call insertfirst/insertlast. Valgrind also complains on my loop where I try to free the memory. I get something like this:

```
Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==4548==    at 0x4C2C2BC: operator delete(void*)(in/usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4548==    by 0x4007D6: main (code6.cpp:67)
==4548==  Address 0xffefffea0 is on thread 1's stack
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct Node {
    Node() : data(T()), next(nullptr) {}
    Node(T d, Node * p) : data(d), next(p) {}
    T data;
    Node<T> * next;
};

template <class T>
void insertlast (Node<T> * p, T data) { 
    if (p == nullptr) {
        p = new Node<T>(data, nullptr);
    } else {
        while (p -> next != nullptr) {
            p = p -> next;
        }
        p -> next = new Node<T>(data, nullptr);
    }
}

template <class T>
void insertfirst (Node<T> * & p, const T & data) {
    Node<T> * tmp = new Node<T>(data, p);
    p = tmp;
}

template <class T>
void printNode(Node<T> *& node) {
    cout << node->data << " -> ";
    while (node->next != nullptr) {
        node = node->next;
        cout << node->data << " -> ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}


template <class T>
void printNode2(Node<T> & node) {
    cout << node.data << " -> ";
    while (node.next != nullptr) {
        node = *node.next;
        cout << node.data << " -> ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}


int main() {
    Node<int> node;
    Node<int> * temp = &node;
    Node<int> * ref = &node;

    insertlast(ref, 5);
    insertfirst(ref, 3);
    insertlast(ref, 6);
    insertfirst(ref, 2);

    //printNode(ref);
    //printNode2(node);

    while(ref->next != nullptr){
        temp = ref->next;
        delete ref;
        ref = temp;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It would be cool if you could help me out to find out what's wrong with the code. My guess is that it's something fishy with the pointer reference in insertfirst, but I can't figure it out.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does `insertlast` not take a `Node<T>*` reference just like `insertfirst`?

Comment: A small note about the question title, it's completely wrong. This question have nothing to do with memory *leaks*.

Comment: The valgrind message is pretty clear: the operation is invalid because the address you're trying to free is on the stack. There is nothing memory-leaky about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `insertfirst` the first time, you will create a new node whose `next` pointer is the statically allocated `node` object from `main`, then when you loop over the list to delete the nodes in it, you will try to delete this `node` object.

What you should do, if you want a sentinel object at the head of the list, is to make its `next` pointer point to the new node, and the new node should have its next pointer set to `p->next`. So something like

```
template <class T>
void insertfirst (Node<T> * head, const T & data) {
    Node<T> * tmp = new Node<T>(data, head->next);
    head->next = tmp;
}
```

---

Finally a hint on how to debug these things: Draw it *on paper!* After every operation, draw it out on paper, and problems like this would have been very easy to spot.

Comment: That may look obvious but the _draw it on paper_ advice is really really important :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `insertlast` function, if the argument `p` is `NULL`, then your code will leak an instance of Node. You create the new instance and assign its address to `p`, but once you leave the function, `p` goes out of scope and you no longer have a pointer to the newly created instance.

I suppose you wanted to pass a reference to `p` like in your `insertfirst` function, but forgot to put the `&` char in there.

Comment: As an aside, I find your memory management here very strange. You create the head node on the stack in your `main` function and then proceed to create new nodes on the free store in your functions, which you then delete again in main. I understand that this is just an exercise, but you should always strive to make your memory management as safe as possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is inconsistent interface of these two functions

```
template <class T>
void insertlast (Node<T> * p, T data) { 
    if (p == nullptr) {
        p = new Node<T>(data, nullptr);
    } else {
        while (p -> next != nullptr) {
            p = p -> next;
        }
        p -> next = new Node<T>(data, nullptr);
    }
}

template <class T>
void insertfirst (Node<T> * & p, const T & data) {
    Node<T> * tmp = new Node<T>(data, p);
    p = tmp;
}
```

In the first function parameters are declared like `Node<T> * p, T data` while in the second function they are declared like `Node<T> * & p, const T & data`

In the first function you also shall pass the first parameter by reference. Otherwise `p` is a local variable of the function and changes of it will not influence to the original argument.

In can be defined the following way

```
template <class T>
void insertlast ( Node<T> * &p, const T &data ) 
{ 
    if ( p == nullptr ) 
    {
        p = new Node<T>(data, nullptr);
    } 
    else 
    {
        Node<T> *tmp = p;
        while ( tmp->next != nullptr ) 
        {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }

        tmp->next = new Node<T>( data, nullptr );
    }
}
```

Also you have to initialize the first node in main to nullptr

```
Node<int> *node = nullptr;
```

It is a bad idea to define the first node of the list in the stack. It is simply an invalid design.